# How did these characters die in the real world?

Tags: project-nemesis

In *Nemesis*, by Brandon Reichs, we learn that Min and Noah are

> test subjects for a program designed to preserve the human race from destruction by converting their minds to an electronic form.

Once everyone in the main test group has undergone this process, they revive when “killed,” appearing at one of a variety of reset points around the facsimile of Fire Lake. This makes plenty of sense: if they’re just code, they don’t even have to really die: they can just be reset whenever they would otherwise have died.

However, Noah, Min, and the other two betas were experiencing these episodes before they were computerized: that is, they were killed every two years on their birthday, and then revived at one of the reset points. They *must* have been outside the simulation (that is, they couldn’t have been prematurely computerized), because everyone around them who was aware of Project Nemesis was *terrified* of the imminent destruction of Earth at the hands of Nemesis.

**How could Min and the other beta subjects die and resurrect in the real world, before the simulation had even begun?**

Comment: Wow. I guess someone actually read this.